# pyspark error while using loadlabledpoints RDD

Tags: parsing, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, libsvm

I am using pyspark

I read a libsvm file, transpose it, and then save it again.

I save every data row as [MLUtils.labeledpoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.html) object with sparse data

I tried using MLUtils.saveaslibsvm and than read the files using MLUtils.loadlibsvm, and I get the following error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: [
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)  at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1055)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)  at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

I read in the [MLUtils](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.html) page that if you want to use loadlabeledpoints, you need to save the data using RDD.saveAsTextFile but when i do this, i get

> 17/08/10 16:55:51 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID
>   3, 192.168.1.205, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot
>   parse a double from: [    at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.NumericParser$.parseDouble(NumericParser.scala:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.NumericParser$.parseArray(NumericParser.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.NumericParser$.parseTuple(NumericParser.scala:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.NumericParser$.parse(NumericParser.scala:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint$.parse(LabeledPoint.scala:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$$anonfun$loadLabeledPoints$1.apply(MLUtils.scala:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$$anonfun$loadLabeledPoints$1.apply(MLUtils.scala:195)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
>     at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.to(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.toBuffer(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.toArray(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "["    at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)   at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.NumericParser$.parseDouble(NumericParser.scala:117)
>     ... 30 more

How can i save RDD of labeled points as libsvm format and than load it back from the disk using pyspark?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that writing the LabledPoints to file did not use the libsvm format and then it was hard to re-read it.

I solved it by creating the labled point in memory, and then before writing it to file, i converted it to libsvm format string, and then wrote it as text, after, i was able to read it as libsvm format

```
def pointToLibsvmRow(point):
    s = point.features.reshape(2,-1, order="C").transpose().astype("str")
    pairs = [str(int(float(point.label)))] + ["%s:%s" % (str(int(float(a))), b) for a, b in s.tolist()]
    st = " ".join(pairs)
    return st
```